# Inserting a tab before every word in bold in a long piece of text

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace

I have a long vocabulary list in an MS Word document, with English words in non-bold, followed by Hungarian words in bold. I am trying to format it for use in the Anki flashcards software, and need to put a tab in between each non-bold word and each bold word. I imagine that I can do this with FIND AND REPLACE, but can't quite work it out, which is driving me mad! I have attached a screenshot of how it is now showing current formatting, and another showing how I need it to be. The list is thousands of lines long, so this is not something I want to do manually...

Very grateful for any help with this!

[How the list looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVbsp.png)

[How the list should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAGeu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Press CTRL + H to open the "Find and Replace" tool
2. Click into the "Find what" line, then in the bottom left click on "More" and again in the bottom left click on "Format" and open the "Font" settings
   [image]
3. In the new window, under "Font Style" select "Bold" and click on "OK"
   [image]
4. Click into the "Replace with" line and enter `^t^&`
5. Click on "Replace" to test it for the first (or a few more entries) and once you feel comfortable that everything works, click on "Replace All".
   [image]

FYI: The `^t` is the tab character and the `^&` is basically a copy of the found entry.

Comment: This worked brilliantly, thanks so much. The only small issue is that in some cases it puts a tab in front of every bold word, so that where there are two translations of the English word you get ENGLISH WORD tab HUNGARIAN WORD tab HUNGARIAN WORD. This seems to be in those cases where the two Hungarian words in bold are separated by a single space rather than a comma and a space.

Comment: You might want to try it with putting `*^13` in the "Find what" field. This will seach for everything (`*`) until a line break (`^13`). Note, that you'll have to activate "Use wildcards" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If it can't be done in Word directly, I would copy/paste it over to a different editor that uses, e.g., markdown, in the raw formatting.  I would then use the formatting symbols as delimiters for the search and replace (double astericks in your case), then copy/paste it back in and generate the result, which you can then copy back into Word.

Comment: Thanks, the solution in Word worked pretty well, but thanks for this, I'll keep it up my sleeve for when it comes in handy!